# Phonegap: plugins not found in android

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

it seems that i messed up something with my configuration. After an Update of cordova and some cleaning operations all plugins cant be found by android. It says:

```
10-10 20:49:47.040      611-611/com.phonegap.helloworld W/System.err﹕ java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.cordova.ContactManager
10-10 20:49:47.050      611-611/com.phonegap.helloworld W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
10-10 20:49:47.050      611-611/com.phonegap.helloworld W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:234)
10-10 20:49:47.060      611-611/com.phonegap.helloworld W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:181)
10-10 20:49:47.060      611-611/com.phonegap.helloworld W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.cordova.PluginEntry.getClassByName(PluginEntry.java:117)
10-10 20:49:47.060      611-611/com.phonegap.helloworld W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.cordova.PluginEntry.createPlugin(PluginEntry.java:93)
10-10 20:49:47.070      611-611/com.phonegap.helloworld W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.cordova.PluginManager.getPlugin(PluginManager.java:267)
10-10 20:49:47.070      611-611/com.phonegap.helloworld W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.cordova.PluginManager.execHelper(PluginManager.java:221)
10-10 20:49:47.070      611-611/com.phonegap.helloworld W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.cordova.PluginManager.exec(PluginManager.java:216)
10-10 20:49:47.080      611-611/com.phonegap.helloworld W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.cordova.ExposedJsApi.exec(ExposedJsApi.java:53)
10-10 20:49:47.080      611-611/com.phonegap.helloworld W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.cordova.CordovaChromeClient.onJsPrompt(CordovaChromeClient.java:221)
10-10 20:49:47.091      611-611/com.phonegap.helloworld W/System.err﹕ at android.webkit.CallbackProxy.handleMessage(CallbackProxy.java:566)
10-10 20:49:47.091      611-611/com.phonegap.helloworld W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-10 20:49:47.091      611-611/com.phonegap.helloworld W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
10-10 20:49:47.100      611-611/com.phonegap.helloworld W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
10-10 20:49:47.100      611-611/com.phonegap.helloworld W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-10 20:49:47.100      611-611/com.phonegap.helloworld W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
10-10 20:49:47.110      611-611/com.phonegap.helloworld W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
10-10 20:49:47.110      611-611/com.phonegap.helloworld W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
10-10 20:49:47.110      611-611/com.phonegap.helloworld W/System.err﹕ at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-10 20:49:47.121      611-611/com.phonegap.helloworld W/System.err﹕ Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.cordova.ContactManager
10-10 20:49:47.130      611-611/com.phonegap.helloworld W/System.err﹕ ... 19 more
10-10 20:49:47.140      611-611/com.phonegap.helloworld W/System.err﹕ Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.cordova.ContactManager in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.phonegap.helloworld-1.apk]
10-10 20:49:47.150      611-611/com.phonegap.helloworld W/System.err﹕ at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
10-10 20:49:47.150      611-611/com.phonegap.helloworld W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
10-10 20:49:47.150      611-611/com.phonegap.helloworld W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
10-10 20:49:47.150      611-611/com.phonegap.helloworld W/System.err﹕ ... 19 more
10-10 20:49:47.161      611-611/com.phonegap.helloworld I/System.out﹕ Error adding plugin org.apache.cordova.ContactManager.
10-10 20:49:47.161      611-611/com.phonegap.helloworld D/PluginManager﹕ exec() call to unknown plugin: Contacts
10-10 20:49:47.180      611-611/com.phonegap.helloworld I/Web Console﹕ error in contacts: at file:///android_asset/www/js/contacts.js:30
```

How can i get the plugins working?

I am using phonegap 3.0.0c

Answer (score 0):

If you navigate to your phonegap root directory and type "phonegap local plugin list", what does it say?

If nothing happens then try to reinstall every plugin with "phonegap local plugin add link/to/plugin".

But if the plugin listing generate an output with every installed plugin, try to delete the "android.json" in the plugins directory and build your android project again.

It should create a new android project with all plugins, which you downloaded previously.

Comment: The "phonegap local plugin ad... " did not get any new files. After the deletion of android.json and the android folder i get the following error: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: ContactFindOptions at file:///android_asset/www/js/contacts.js:26

Comment: Did you used the link to the git repositories for the plugin installation? For example the "device" plugin install would be like this: `phonegap local plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-device.git` . You can find every link on this page, just scroll down a bit to the plugin listing: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-line%20Interface

Comment: yes, i used this one. I think it is now a problem of javascript.